# laravel 5.1 error controller Missing argument 1

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

i have a foreach with my list of products in my index.blade.php, it work well, now i'm tryng to filter, i done my menu with my categories and genders.

I would like show products with category = "t-shirt" and gender= "woman" but i have this error:

> ErrorException in StoreController.php line 36: Missing argument 1 for
>   dixard\Http\Controllers\StoreController::products()

**i'm using this link**:

```
<a href="{{url('shop', ['category'=> 't-shirt', 'gender' => 'woman'])}}" title="">
     <span>Woman</span>
</a>
```

**my route**:

```
Route::get('shop', 'StoreController@index');
Route::get('shop/{category}/{gender}','StoreController@products');
```

**My controller**

```
public function products($category, $gender)
    {


            $gender_id= Gender::where('gender', $gender )->first();
            $category_id= Category::where('name', $category)->first();
            $filter = ['gender_id' => $gender_id->id, 'category_id' => $category_id->id];
            $products = Product::where($filter)->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
            $categories = Category::all();
            return view('store.index', compact('products','categories'));   


    }
```

Comment: which line is 36 in your controller code?

Comment: @Yani line 36 --> public function products($category, $gender)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **named routes**. There's nothing special with this.

```
Route::get('shop/{category}/{gender}', [
  'uses' => StoreController@products', 
  'as' => 'shopRoute'
]);
```

And your URL:

```
route('shopRoute', ['category'=> 't-shirt', 'gender' => 'woman'])
```

Comment: I tryed! same error: ErrorException in StoreController.php line 36:
Missing argument 1 for dixard\Http\Controllers\StoreController::products()

Answer (score 0):

Use the route function (https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing)

```
 <a href="{{route('shop', ['category'=> 't-shirt', 'gender' => 'woman'])}}" title="">
 <span>Woman</span>
 </a>
```

Comment: i have this error if i use route instead url :  "  ErrorException in UrlGenerator.php line 306:
Route [shop] not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\2016\resources\views\layouts\principal.blade.php) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\2016\resources\views\layouts\principal.blade.php) "

Comment: the result is--> page not found

Answer (score 0):

i fixed like this:

```
Route::get('shop','ShopController@index');
Route::get('shop/{categoryA}','ShopController@category'); 
Route::get('shop/{categoryB}/{genderB}','ShopController@categoryGender'); 
Route::get('shop/{categoryC}/{genderC}/{slugC}','ShopController@product');
```

I dont know why but i changed that of variables that i pass to my route and it work!